Не получается проверить наличие подстроки в строке python
Максимально простая задача, но я искренне не понимаю, почему не получается правильно проверить, есть ли в строке другая подстрока. При запуске этого кода выводится "апп", а должно "обязат"
text = "обязательство"

if "долевом" or "характерист" in text:
    print("апп")
elif "обязательство" or "обяз" in text:
    print("обязат")


В дублирующем вопросе про код вида a=="ноль" or "нулевой", но суть та же что и в данном случае.

Логическое выражение or отделяет 2 логических утверждения, вот и получает что вы спрашиваете: если "долевом" или "характерист" в тексте. Как понимаете первое утверждение не несёт смысловой нагрузки и будет всегда выдавать истину.
Правильно записать так:
text = "обязательство"

if "долевом" in text or "характерист" in text:
    print("апп")
elif "обязательство" in text or "обяз" in text:
    print("обязат")

